# Javascript error on Window Chrome but not Mac Chrome

Tags: javascript

I have some js running on load of my website in order to customize some things for non mac browsers.

```
function checkOs(){
    var os = navigator.appVersion;
    if(os.indexOf('Mac') === -1){
        //if not mac, change the font on the homepage
        var big = document.getElementById('home_p');
        big.style.fontFamily = 'good-futura';
        big.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    }
}
```

On mac it runs fine, but this may be because it never gets into the if statement, I'm not sure how javacript is normally parsed.

On windows, I get a `Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'style' of null` on line 6, which means `var big` returned null. However, if I go into the chrome console and execute each of the lines in the if statement, everything works as expected.

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: When is this function called in relation to the rendering of the "home_p" element?  Perhaps you need to wrap the call in a "`document.onload`" event handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when do you call this function? maybe the DOM hasn't finished loading so the getElementById will return null.

try console.log(big) on line 7 and reload the page if you get undefined chances are the DOM isn't ready when you call getElement.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I was just talking to someone who was doing this the other day. Thanks for the quick response.